How do you scale out a flink process to use more processes?
I have a batch job that involves a set of map and reduce steps that I've successfully converted to an Apache Flink application.
As a proof of concept, I deployed this via docker-compose using 3 taskmanagers. However I only ever see logs coming from 1 of them.
Is there a way to force Flink to distribute the job to all available taskmanagers?

If your source has a parallelism of 1, or it only generates data from one partition (e.g. it's a Kafka topic with 3 partitions, and only 1 has data) then only one downstream chain will receive any records.
If that's the case, a rebalance() after the source, or or keyby() (assuming a reasonable number of unique keys) would trigger a network shuffle that distributes data to all Task Managers.

Thanks to this amazing video I found the answer. It's all about the allocated slots in each taskmanager, which is controlled by the env variable taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots.
As soon as I set this to 1, it forces my job to fan out across all available taskmanagers. I placed log statements in each map/filter/flatMap commands and I can see them printed out evenly across from each taskmanager's logs.
Sample docker-compose.yml:
version: "2.2"
services:
  jobmanager:
    image: flink:latest
    command: standalone-job --job-classname com.example.Example --jars /opt/flink/usrlib2/flink-learning-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    volumes:
      - ./lib:/opt/flink/usrlib
      - ./target:/opt/flink/usrlib2
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        parallelism.default: 3

  taskmanager:
    image: flink:latest
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    scale: 3
    command: taskmanager
    volumes:
      - ./lib:/opt/flink/usrlib
      - ./target:/opt/flink/usrlib2
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 1
        parallelism.default: 3

